# Magento2.3 - How to set text column table value default is None using declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, declarative-schema

I want to create a custom table using `db_schema.xml` like that contains column like this:

[image]
[image]

I tried to do it like this:

```
<column name="description" nullable="false" default="null" xsi:type="text"/>
```

but always got an error like this:

```
The XML in file "/var/www/M2/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml" is invalid:
Element 'column', attribute 'default': The attribute 'default' is not allowed.
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @aravind see my updated question

Comment: change nullable="false" to nullable="true"

Comment: @SohelRana i need this column not nullable with default value _None_

Answer (score 3):

**For Magento2.3 :**

Add below code in file  db_schema.xml.

```
<column xsi:type="text" name="description" nullable="true" comment="Description"/>
```

Then run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName
```

This will add new column "description" in table with **default value "NULL"**. No need to specify default="NULL" in schema definition.

Comment: Right on! I just ran into this same problem. Had a bunch of column values with the string "NULL" in them. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `nullable="false"` your setting the column **should not** be null and you are setting its default value to null, so, here you are creating a conflict for an interpreter I guess. Try the below code and let us know the result.

```
<column xsi:type="text" name="description" nullable="true" default="NULL" comment="Description"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName
```

then change this

```
<column xsi:type="text" name="description" nullable="false" comment="Description"/>
```

and finally run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to pass default value, then we need to check whether the default value is compatible with the type of field we are using is

**default** Initializes the column with the specified default value. The default value should have the same datatype defined in xsi:type.

so for having any int value as default
use it like

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="item_seq" nullable="true" default="99" comment="Item Sequence"/>
```

For more info, you can consider following link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I just ran into this issue today while using Magento 2.4.1. I'm pretty sure the answer is you can't set a default value for a column with type of text/mediumtext/longtext. None of those schema files (found under vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\etc\types\texts) include a "default" attribute definition. You can probably update the schema by including your own .xsd file to define a "default" attribute, but short of that  this isn't possible. I would note however that while the website is in "default" mode you can run your "setup:upgrade" command just fine with the "default" attribute in your db_schema.xml file. Though the fact that in "developer" mode these validations fail seem to indicate trying to circumspect the issue this way is not a good idea. (I am pretty new to Magento 2 so take this answer with a grain of salt.)

Answer (score -1):

**Change: xsi:type="text" <==to==> xsi:type="varchar"**

Ex:

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="image_position" nullable="true" default="full" comment="image_position"/>
```

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=MyCompany_MyModule
```